# Socialization Gem for Rails - How Can I Display the Number of Likes a Post has Received

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the [Socialization gem](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) in my first Ruby on Rails project.

The application has photos, posted by users. The photos are placed in sort of activity stream, much like Instagram.

I have successfully implemented Socialization.

Users can like other user's posts, which really are a photos, called a Plate.

How can I identify and display the number of likes a Plate has received?

From my view, along with the code I tried (last line) which is not displaying an accurate number, only returning 0:

```
<% if current_user.likes?(plate) %>
    <%= link_to "Unlike", plate_unlike_path(plate), :method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Like", plate_like_path(plate), :method => :post, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
<% end %>
<br />
<p>Number of likes <%= plate.likers(Plate).count %></p>
```

And from the socialization controller:

```
def like        
  target_plate=Plate.find(params[:plate_id])
  current_user.like!(target_plate)      
  redirect_to plate_path(target_plate)  
end

def unlike      
  target_plate=Plate.find(params[:plate_id])
  current_user.unlike!(target_plate)
  redirect_to plate_path(target_plate)  
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong class to `plate.likers`. You should pass in the class that would be liking the plate like: `plate.likers(User).count`.

Comment: Wonderfully simple and effective :) Thank you for taking the time to help.